# NSMutableArray with NSDictionary to Labels without the surrounding brackets

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I'm making a scoreboard for my game. And when I do a NSLog of the data it comes out as this:

```
{
    name = TTY;
    score = "3.366347";
}
```

So my question is how do I remove this brackets and also just grab the name (TTY) and score (3.36 without the quotations) and place them in variable for me to put into labels.

Currently I can place them in labels but they have the lingering curly braces "{" and "}".

Any hints would be helpful as I'm happy to search further I just don't know the vocab to search for it.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For NSDictionary if you want to get the values you use [`objectForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey%3a) method;

```
[scoreDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

In your case the method will return `TTY`
You can store this in a variable like normal:

```
NSString *entryName = [scoreDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

For NSArray (and NSMutableArray) you use [`objectAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex%3a) method;

```
[scoresArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

I'm guessing that you have many NSDictionary in the NSArray, in which case you can combine the two methods above and get;

```
[[scoresArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

which will give you the value of `name` in the first dictionary of the array.

Also if you want to access multiple key values you can use;

```
NSDictionary *entry = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *entryName = [entry objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *entryScore = [entry objectForKey:@"score"];
```

Comment: Thanks very much it worked. I didn't know you could combine it like that.